# C++ constraint on callable types as template parameters

Tags: c++, scala, templates

I'm trying to port the following Scala code to C++:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

I've tried something like:

```
template<template <typename> class F>
struct Functor {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    static F<B> map(const F<A> &fa, ??? f);  // What's the type of `f`?
};
```

But I don't know how to express the type of `f` (which in Scala is `A => B`, or `Function1[A, B]`). Using `std::function` makes the compiler unable to do useful type inference, and also makes using lambdas awkward (I need to explicitly specify the template parameter, like

```
Functor<List>::map<Foo, Bar>(foos, [](const Foo &foo) -> Bar { return foo.toBar(); });
```

, otherwise the compiler just can't seem to infer what `B` is). A workaround seems to be:

```
template<template <typename> class F>
struct Functor {
    template <typename A, typename A2B>
    static auto map(const F<A> &fa, A2B f) -> F<decltype(f(fa[0]))>;
};
```

But this looks ugly, and `F<A>` might not always support the brackets operator (or `::value_type`, for that matter). Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: What does that Scala code mean?

Comment: @T.C. For example, if you have a list `nums` (of type `List[Int]`) that contains `1, 2, 3`, and a `Functor[List]`, you can do `Functor[List].map(nums)(x => (x + 1).toString)` and get back a new list that contains `"2", "3", "4"`. It's similar to `std::transform`. The `F[_]` syntax basically means `F` is a type that can "contain" another type.

Comment: Are you bound to C++11 or C++14 is available?

Comment: @AntonSavin C++14 is available.

Comment: Could [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) help?

Comment: I.e. `typename std::result_of<A2B(A)>::type` ? (I'm not entirely sure how you want to use that static member function, or define it.)

Comment: @DanielJour Ah, that helps clean up things a lot. Is there any way to specify the return type and _then_ constrain the function type, instead of specifying the function type and then inferring the return type?

Comment: What does the *body* do?  The signature is easy; but even without it, you could deduce it from the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `std::result_of_t` and generic lambdas you'll have nice enough calling code:

```
template<template <typename> class F>
struct Functor {    
    template <typename A, typename A2B>
    static auto map(const F<A> &fa, A2B f) -> F<std::result_of_t<A2B(A)>>;
};

auto bars = Functor<std::vector>::map(foos, [](const auto& foo) { return foo.toBar(); });
```

Note however, that most of standard C++ containers have more than one template parameter. The easiest way so to make this code work with them you'll have to change definition of `Functor` to

```
template<template <typename...> class F>
struct Functor {
```

And you won't be able to specify other template parameters, e.g `Allocator` for the resulting container type, unless you provide a dedicated specialization for particular container.

Comment: Thanks! The last sentence in your answer turned out to be extremely useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ way to do this is to define a function.  Call it fmap.

Then clients who want to support it override `fmap` as a free function, where argument 1 takes a client object, and argument 2 takes a function that maps from the interior type to some other type.

You can write a trait that expresses "supports fmap" and does the "proper" type conversion, but it is annoying and not worth it.  'Supports fmap' is easier, and as useful.

Similarly for `fbind` etc.